# x86 assembly language, current location counter $ did not return the expected result

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently learning assembly programming by following Kip Irvine's "assembly language x86 programming" book.

For the code before, the result I got after executing the line of code `MOV EAX, listSize` is that `EAX` is equal 18.

I was expecting the variable `listSize` to contain the value 24 (`list` is 4 bytes long, `list2` array is 20 bytes long, therefore when `$ - list`, i.e. the current location counter minus the `list`, I should get 24)

Why is this happening? did I do something wrong?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.DATA
list BYTE 10, 20, 30, 40
list2 BYTE 20 DUP(0)
listSize = ($ - list)

.CODE 
    main PROC 
    MOV EAX, listSize 

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

[image]

Comment: `18` in hexadecimal is `24` decimal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude lol thanks. damn me for making such silly mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displayed values in the registers are all in hexadecimal (base 16), so `00000018` is 24 decimal.

Comment: thanks chris, lol silly me